# Pointing Apache to a SVN repo

Tags: svn, apache, repository, lamp

I have a SVN repo on my server which contains a working version of our prototype. Currently we have the repo checked out, and are using our local dev environment (LAMP) to access the proto, make changes and then commit it.

What I want to know is how to maintain a live working version of the repo in the LAMP stack, so that when we make changes and commit, we want to see it reflected live on the site, so we can test out changes. This will ensure that each of us dont have to maintain a separate dev environment which might cause problems due to difference in versions...

Comment: "What I want to know is how to maintain a live working version of the repo in the LAMP stack, so that when we make changes and commit, we want to see it reflected live on the site, so we can test out changes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar: basically, I've just added a post-hook commit on the repos which then updates /var/www/_internal : a checked out version of the repository/ies which is then used as the Apache documentroot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use continuous integration tools like [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/), etc. to create daily builds or continuous builds. You could create multiple "projects" within CC for instance "trunk build", "stable build 1.0.x", "stable build 1.1.x", etc.

See Martin Fowler's [Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).